# Mixed and restricted element fails validation with Xmlbeans

Tags: java, xsd, xmlbeans, xmlspy

while working with Xmlbeans, I have noticed that when an element is defined as a restriction from a mixed type, if there is some text in this element the Xmlbeans validation fails.However the same xml file is valid if I run it against schema validation in XmlSpy. Here is the example (I tried to make it as simple as possible):

xml schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="RootElement">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Comment describing your root element</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Child"/>
                <xs:element ref="ChildExtended"/>
                <xs:element ref="ChildRestricted"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Child" type="MixedType"/>
    <xs:element name="ChildRestricted" type="MixedTypeRestricted"/>
    <xs:element name="ChildExtended" type="MixedTypeExtended"/>
    <xs:complexType name="MixedType" mixed="true"/>
    <xs:complexType name="MixedTypeExtended" mixed="true">
        <xs:complexContent mixed="true">
            <xs:extension base="MixedType"/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="MixedTypeRestricted" mixed="true">
        <xs:complexContent mixed="true">
            <xs:restriction base="MixedType"/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

xml file:

```
<RootElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Child>text</Child> 
    <ChildExtended>text1</ChildExtended>
    <ChildRestricted>text2</ChildRestricted>
</RootElement>
```

For XmlSpy, this is valid. Here's what I get when validating with Xmlbeans :

```
Message: Element 'ChildRestricted' with empty content type cannot have text or element content.
Location of invalid XML: <xml-fragment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

As you can see, it is just the child defined as a restricted type that causes the problem. My question is : who is right ? XmlSpy (no error) or Xmlbeans ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has already been commented in issue [XMLBEANS-457](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XMLBEANS-457) you created, [revision 1102771](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1102771) fixes the issue.